# CS50 recover segmentation fault Oct 2020

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm new to coding and started with Harvard's CS50 course. I've written some code for recover for cs50, and tried to run it, but segmentation fault occurs.

In need of some help in identifying what's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
    }

    char filename[8];
    FILE *img = NULL;
    BYTE bytes[512];
    int counter = 0;

    while (fread(bytes, 512, 1, file) == 1)
    {
        if(bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xd8 && bytes[2] == 0xff && (bytes[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 )
        {
            if (counter > 0)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
        }
    }
    if (img == NULL)
    fclose(img);

    if (file == NULL)
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (file == NULL)`: you also need to abort the program. `img = fopen(filename, "w");` you don't check if `img` is NULL. Otherwise I don't see any obvious error. Did you run this with you debugger?

Comment: OT:... and the second error message `"printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");"` is wrong

Comment: `if (img == NULL) fclose(img);` The condition does not make sense. You need to close if the pointers are not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus on this part.

```
else
{
    fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
}
```

Lets say I am reading every 512 byte in the memorycard, could not find any jpeg sign. And the code directly jumps into `else` statement. Lets see what is going on there.

```
fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
```

img is **NULL** here (i.e there is no such an img file created), and fwrite intends to write on non-existing file. Bam! It is segmentation fault. If you add this condition it should be ok.

```
    else if (img != NULL)
    {
        // Write the data to a new jpeg file.
        fwrite(bytes, 512, 1, img);
    }
```